# Relative relativity?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity

Perhaps there is already an answer for this, but I have not found it. The question is: If an object is going a certain speed, say $0.9999c$ (where $c$ is the speed of light), and there is another object behind it going at $0.9990c$, what would the length of the round object be in the perspective of the object going at $0.9990c$? So far, my thinking is the following:

If length is determined by

$ L = L_{o}\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}$

Object 1's length at $v=0.9999c$ is

$ L = L_{o}\sqrt{1-\frac{(0.9999c)^2}{c^2}}$

$ L =(1.9999*10^{-4})L_{o}$

However, the length from the perspective of the second object would be

$L = L_{o}\sqrt{1-\frac{(0.9999c-0.9990c)^2}{c^2}}$

$L \approx L_{o}\sqrt{0.999999}$

$L \approx L_{o}$

Meaning that the distortions of length (and therefore time, momentum, and all other aspects of physics as well) would be negligible if the observer is moving close to the speed of the object in question.

That is my logic on this topic. Is it correct? I thank you in advance for taking the time to quell my curiosity.

Comment: You should be using the [relativistic velocity addition formula](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/einvel2.html#c2).

Answer (score 1):

As @StephenG suggests, you should use velocity composition.

With the given velocities, their relative velocity is
$v/c$=tanh(arctanh(0.9999)-arctanh(0.999))$=0.8182562051095736$
and the gamma factor is
$\gamma$=cosh(arctanh(0.9999)-arctanh(0.999))$=1.7395730258367604$
[using WolframAlpha].
This is not a negligible effect.

Comment: Note much simpler velocity addition formula on the link to that Hyperphysics page is generally simpler to use (and doesn't even require a scientific calculator).

Comment: Okay.  $v=(.9999-.999)/(1-.9999*.999)=
0.81825620511$ and
$\gamma=1/\sqrt{(1-((.9999-.999)/(1-.9999*.999))^2)}=
1.73957302584$ [using Google].

Answer (score -1):

It would be negligible. You are only speaking 1/10,000th of a difference in speed. The difference in speed would have to be **substantial** in order to observe a difference.

$v^2$= the relative velocity of the observer

It seems, however, that you have put the value as the speed of the observer.

Velocity is a vector, speed is a scalar.

In order to utilize the Lorentz equation you would need to establish the length of Observer $B$.

$v_2$=0.0009 (relative velocity)

$c^2$= 299792458 m/s

This equation, however, would be used for observers moving parallel to each other.
You run into a brier patch when dealing with these types of problems (see relativity of simultaneity)

Comment: Relative speed of B and C were respect to A but not the relative speed with respect to each other, if BC went opposite direction, were you suppose to say their relative speed was faster than light?

Comment: In order for him to utilize the Lorentz equation he would need to establish the length of Observer $b$ as well as the velocity, in which case the difference would be almost non-existent. Much like saying that I am traveling at 55.9999 m/s and you are travelling at 55.9990 m/s. It would take me approx. 4 months to catch up to you.

Comment: You forgot the time was also different, an easy rule of thumb was to use relativity for any object >=10%c